# Apache: open_basedir with variable

Tags: php, apache, apache2, directory, open-basedir

I now have this:

```
<Directory ~ "^/home/.*">
php_flag open_basedir "/home/$1"
</Directory>
```

But that doesn't work. How can I refer to that `.*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. Apache does not interpret any variable settings in directives. You can use `%1` style RewriteCond backreferences in some, or `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` even. But most directives use static values.

Specifically PHPs Apache SAPI does not attempt to interpret any `%` or `$` sequences.

There are a few workarounds listed on [Serverfault: Using variables in Apache config files to reduce duplication?](https://serverfault.com/questions/64656/using-variables-in-apache-config-files-to-reduce-duplication). But neither `mod_macro` or `mod_define` will accomplish what you want. You will have to define it for each home directory separately. (That is also what Plesk and Confixx do for multiple accounts.)

Comment: Thnx, we will do it that way then :).